# Getting Facebook profile Album without Iterating through every profile albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
function getAlbumCovers() {
    //first check to see if profile pics already exist in user model

    //create a collection
    var usersCollection = Alloy.Collections.user;

    facebookModule.requestWithGraphPath('me/albums', {
        fields : 'id,name,cover_photo,count,created_time'
    }, 'GET', function(graphResp) {
        //show view indicator before data is fetched
        //$.view_indicator.visible = true;
        setViewIndicator(100, 100, levelColour, 10, true, '30%');
        $.ind.top = '30';
        if (graphResp.success) {
            if (graphResp.result) {
                var rows = [];
                var data = JSON.parse(graphResp.result).data;
                var i = 0;
                var blob;

                for (x in data) {
                    if (data[x].name == "Profile Pictures") {
                        Ti.API.debug(JSON.stringify(data[x]));

                        var numberPhotos = null;
                        var albumTitle = null;

                        //apply transformations

                        if (data[x].count == null) {
                            numberPhotos = 0;

                        } else {

                            numberPhotos = data[x].count;
                            if (numberPhotos > 10) {
                                numberPhotos = 10;

                            } else {

                                numberPhotos = numberPhotos;
                            }
                        }

                        albumTitle = data[x].name + ' (' + numberPhotos + ')';
                        console.log("https://graph.facebook.com/" + (data[x].cover_photo || 0) + "/picture?access_token=" + Alloy.Globals.facebookModule.accessToken + "&type=album");
                        //start
                        // Read the image as a blob
                        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + (data[x].cover_photo || 0) + "/picture?access_token=" + Alloy.Globals.facebookModule.accessToken + "&type=album";

                        var imgView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                            image : url,
                            width : 'auto',
                            height : 'auto'
                        });
                        var imgBlob = imgView.toBlob();
                        var height = imgBlob.height;
                        var width = imgBlob.width;

                        if (height > width) {
                            var pos = (height - width) / 2;
                            var dict = {
                                height : width,
                                width : width,
                                x : 0,
                                y : pos
                            };
                            var newImg = imgBlob.imageAsCropped(dict);
                            //alert(newImg.height);
                        } else if (height < width) {
                            var pos = (width - height) / 2;
                            var dict = {
                                height : height,
                                width : height,
                                x : pos,
                                y : 0
                            };
                            var newImg = imgBlob.imageAsCropped(dict);
                            //alert(newImg.width);
                        } else {
                            //alert(imgBlob.width + '-' + imgBlob.height);
                            var pos = (width - height) / 2;
                            var dict = {
                                height : height,
                                width : height,
                                x : pos,
                                y : 0
                            };
                            var newImg = imgBlob.imageAsCropped(dict);
                        }

                        imgBlob = null;

                        //end
                        var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
                            titleAlb : data[x].name,
                            selectedBackgroundColor : 'transparent',
                            selectionStyle : 'Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE on createTableViewRow',
                            width : '100%',
                            height : '60'
                        });
                        var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                            //image : "https://graph.facebook.com/" + (data[x].cover_photo || 0) + "/picture?access_token=" + Alloy.Globals.facebookModule.accessToken + "&type=album",
                            image : newImg,
                            top : 10,
                            borderColor : levelColour,
                            left : 30,
                            width : '40',
                            height : '40'
                        });

                        if (Alloy.Globals.Platform == 'old') {
                            var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                                text : albumTitle,
                                font : {
                                    visible : true,
                                    color : '#888888',
                                    fontFamily : 'Avenir-Roman',
                                    size : 12,
                                },
                                width : 200,
                                top : 15,
                                color : levelColour,
                                right : '30dp',
                                height : 'auto'
                            });
                        } else if (Alloy.Globals.Platform == '6') {
                            var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                                text : albumTitle,
                                font : {
                                    visible : true,
                                    color : '#888888',
                                    fontFamily : 'Avenir-Roman',
                                    size : 12,
                                },
                                width : 200,
                                top : 15,
                                color : levelColour,
                                right : '85dp',
                                height : 'auto'
                            });

                        } else if (Alloy.Globals.Platform == '6+') {
                            var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                                text : albumTitle,
                                font : {
                                    visible : true,
                                    color : '#888888',
                                    fontFamily : 'Avenir-Roman',
                                    size : 12,
                                },
                                width : 200,
                                top : 15,
                                color : levelColour,
                                right : '105dp',
                                height : 'auto'
                            });
                        }

                        row.add(image);
                        row.add(title);
                        rows.push(row);

                        i++;
                        console.log(i);

                        //set table rows
                        $.tableview.setData(rows);

                        //end
                        $.view_indicator.visible = false;
                        break;

                    }
                }

            }

        } else {
            $.view_indicator.visible = false;
            if (e.error) {
                alert(e.error);
            } else {
                alert("Unkown result");
            }
        }
    });
```

}

Here is my code, as you can see I am having calling the Facebook api graph iterating through every album, and then detecting the profile album. The problem with this approach is that if the user has a 1000 albums, the for loop can take forever to find the profile album.

Anyone know of a quicker way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such mechanism available in Graph API.

Also, your proposed method is unreliable at best, since not everybody uses Facebook in the English language, and for those that don't, the album might not be called "Profile Pictures".

The best way to get a user's current profile picture (without the album) is by fetching [`/user/picture`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)

Comment: What's the work around to this? I am reliant on getting profile pictures from fb for an app.

Comment: changed my language to french, then made api call seems as though it is stored as "profile pictures".

Comment: There is no workaround (to my knowledge). I don't think Facebook renames the album if you change your language settings. However, if you had created your Facebook profile while using e.g. the French language setting, the album might have a different name.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have decided to just print out all of the albums and put a limit on how many albums I return.